# SQL duplicate row

Tags: php, sql, join

I have a big filter with many options and want to generate the query for sql automaticle and without many code.

GET:

```
searchvalue=abc
&title=abc
&description=abc
&category=1
&subcategory=2
&zip=7
&city=ke
&country=DE
```

SQL:

```
SELECT activity.* FROM activity,subcategory,city,country 
WHERE activity.title LIKE '%abc%' OR activity.description LIKE '%abc%' 
AND subcategory.SubID = 2 
AND city.zip LIKE '%7%' 
AND city.City LIKE '%ke%' 
AND country.CShort= 'DE'
```

With this options, I have 1 row in my database.
The answer is this row many times, many many times.

I know that the sql duplicate a row, when a table is not used in a WHERE clausel - but why he do it now and how can I solve that?

Edit: I have a ER, but the database is in german (school project), maybe it help you to understand:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing a `JOIN` on three different tables without any `JOIN` conditions. This is giving you a cartesian product of the three tables, which would account for the huge number of rows. Check out [this resource](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: @user1878413, either use a `JOIN` or bind the tables in the `WHERE` clause; but you *MUST* do something.

Comment: You are doing a join right here : `FROM activity,subcategory,city,country `

Comment: You don't HAVE to use a join, but without it, you're going to get EVERY row on table `activity`, joined with EVERY row on table `subcategory`, joined with EVERY row on `city`, joined with EVERY row on `country`. I imagine that's not what you want.

Comment: @user1878413, and you have another problem, `WHERE activity.title LIKE '%abc%' OR activity.description LIKE '%abc%'` should be `WHERE (activity.title LIKE '%abc%' OR activity.description LIKE '%abc%')`; order of operations 101.

Comment: Can you, please, how the tables activity,subcategory,city,country are connected to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a cross product by selecting multiple tables. SQL will return every row from the one table combined with every row in the other table.

For example in a database with table a

```
|------|----------|
| idA  | textA    |
|------|----------|
|   1  | fooA     |
|   2  | barA     |
|------|----------|
```

and table b

```
|------|----------|
| idB  | textB    |
|------|----------|
|   1  | fooB     |
|   2  | barB     |
|------|----------|
```

when you do

```
SELECT * FROM a, b
```

you would get

```
|------|----------|------|----------|
| idA  | textA    | idB  | textB    |
|------|----------|------|----------|
|   1  | fooA     |   1  | fooA     |
|   1  | fooA     |   2  | barA     |
|   2  | barA     |   1  | fooB     |
|   2  | barA     |   2  | barB     |
|------|----------|------|----------|
```

To combine these rows logically you do a JOIN. That means you tell in your query which rows belong together. You can do so by JOIN clause or without JOIN clause directly in the WHERE clause.
Back to the example you would do

```
SELECT * FROM a, b
WHERE a.idA = b.idB

-- or

SELECT * FROM a
JOIN b ON a.idA = b.idB
```

you would get only 2 rows.

```
|------|----------|------|----------|
| idA  | textA    | idB  | textB    |
|------|----------|------|----------|
|   1  | fooA     |   1  | fooA     |
|   2  | barA     |   2  | barB     |
|------|----------|------|----------|
```

---

To answer your question:
You have to support JOIN/WHERE clauses to connect your tables `activity`, `subcategory`, `city` and `country` according to your database schema.

I don't know your table structures but for example clauses like this:

```
WHERE
    ...
AND city.country_id = country.id
AND activity.subcategory_id = subcategory.id
AND ...
```